# query update não atualiza o banco de dados por causa de 1 campo

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, tenho um problema bem estranho. Quando eu executo o meu UPDATE na query preenchendo o todos os campos menos o VALOR PRODUTO, ele simplesmente não atualiza nada. Se eu preencher o campo VALOR PRODUTO ele atualiza normal todos os campos. Se eu removo o `valor_produto='$valorprod'` da query ele atualiza normal, independente se estão todos os campos preenchidos ou não. O que pode ser?

Pagina save.php:

```
<?php 

define('host','localhost');
define('usuario','root');
define('senha','');
define('db','bd');
$conexaoa = mysqli_connect(host,usuario,senha,db);



  $codigo = $_POST['cod_produto'];
  $categoria = $_POST['cat_produto'];
  $descricao = $_POST['descricao_produto'];
  $quantidade = $_POST['qnt_total'];
  $valorprod = $_POST['valor_produto'];

  $queri = "UPDATE cad_produtos SET cat_produto='$categoria',descricao_produto='$descricao',qnt_total='$quantidade',valor_produto='$valorprod' WHERE cod_produto='$codigo'";
  $resultadoa = mysqli_query($conexaoa, $queri) or die(mysqli_error($conexaoa));
  if($resultadoa){
   echo 'atualizado';
  }


?>
```

Pagina que estão os inputs:

```
<div class="modal-content" style="width:900px;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label>Código do Produto</label>
            <input type="text" id="cod_produto" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>Categoria</label>
            <select id="cat_produto" class="selectpicker" data-width="99%" data-live-search="true">
            <option selected></option>>
                        <?php while($dados_cat = $result_categorias->fetch_array()){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $dados_cat["categoria"] ?>"><?php echo $dados_cat["categoria"] ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label>Descrição</label>
            <input type="text" id="descricao_produto" class="form-control" style="width: 405px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label>Quantidade Total</label>
            <input type="text" id="qnt_total" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label>Valor Unitário</label>
            <input type="text" id="valor_produto" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="cod_prod" class="form-control">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default float-sm-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn primary float-right">Update</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Script que puxa os dados da tabela para o modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','a[data-role=editar]',function(){
            var cod_produto = $(this).data('id');
            var cat_produto = $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=cat_produto]').text();
            var descricao_produto = $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=descricao_produto]').text();
            var qnt_total = $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=qnt_total]').text();
            var valor_produto = $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=valor_produto]').text();

            $('#cod_produto').val(cod_produto);
            $('#cod_prod').val(cod_produto);
            $('#cat_produto').val(cat_produto);
            $('#cat_produto').selectpicker('render');
            $('#descricao_produto').val(descricao_produto);
            $('#qnt_total').val(qnt_total);
            $('#valor_produto').val(valor_produto);
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
        });

        $('#save').click(function(){
            var cod_produto = $('#cod_prod').val();
            var cat_produto = $('#cat_produto').val();
            var descricao_produto = $('#descricao_produto').val();
            var qnt_total = $('#qnt_total').val();
            var valor_produto = $('#valor_produto').val();

            $.ajax({
                url         : 'save.php',
                method      : 'post',
                data        : {cat_produto : cat_produto , descricao_produto : descricao_produto , qnt_total : qnt_total , valor_produto : valor_produto , cod_produto : cod_produto},
                success     : function(response){
                    $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=cat_produto]').text(cat_produto);
                    $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=descricao_produto]').text(descricao_produto);
                    $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=qnt_total]').text(qnt_total);
                    $('#'+cod_produto).children('td[data-target=valor_produto]').text(valor_produto);
                    $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Provavelmente alguma validação de tipo do campo no banco, gerando um erro

Comment: Coloque um `console.log(response)` no início da function do `success:` e veja o que mostra. Provavelmente um erro no PHP.

Comment: Provavelmente a alguma restrição no campo valor_produto, por exemplo não pode ser null e sua string $valorprod talvez seja null, como disseram da um console.log(response) e veja o que o PHP esta te retornando.

Comment: Seu código fonte aparenta estar ok, porém como foi dito anteriormente, pode ser que exista alguma restrição na sua tabela para a coluna valor_produto que esta impedindo sua atualização. Se possível, adicione na descrição do seu problema o script SQL da criação da sua tabela para uma melhor análise.